# Setting panel.border in ggplot theme turns panel background white (wipes out the plot itself)

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, panel

I would like to make the border of my plots a certain color other than black. I notice that if I set the default theme to theme_bw() using:

```
theme_set(theme_bw())
```

that I can set the border to the color I want using

```
theme(panel.border = element_rect(color="darkred", size=0.5, linetype="solid").
```

That seems to work ok. The border of each panel, whether it's a faceted plot or a single plot, takes on the "darkred" color and the rest of the plot is the same as it was before I changed the panel.border.

However, if I use a different default theme, say theme_gray() or theme_classic(), then the border changes but the contents of each of the facets is wiped out (completely white).

Any idea what is causing this difference in behavior or what I can do to fix it?  I would like to use theme_gray() and put a thin colored line around the border of each facet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Help page of the `theme()` says that `panel.borded=` `This should be used with fill=NA` because it covers panels.

For the `theme_bw()` there is already `panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA,colour = "grey50")`, so when you use your statement only color changes and fill remains as `NA`.

For `theme_grey()` and `theme_bw()` there is `panel.border = element_blank()` so when you add your statement, `color=` and `fill=` are changed because previously this element was blank and default value for `rect` is `fill="white"` (at least for `theme_grey()`).

Use

```
+ theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA,color="darkred", size=0.5, 
                                    linetype="solid"))
```

Comment: Thanks, Didzis.  Probably would've taken me a few more days before I went to the Help page.  The problem is not completely solved, though.  When I tack your suggestion onto the end of a ggplot command

Comment: ...oops... it works correctly.  But when I add it to my theme, it does not do anything.

Comment: I solved this second problem.  Turned out to be a typo in my theme.  Thanks for your help.  Much appreciated.

Comment: This is useful, thanks for sharing